# How to implement an object in Ruby with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Absolute beginner in Ruby.

I need to create a class that contains the following keys:

[image: Dict API that I need to follow]

I know that this might be the structure, but can anybody help me with syntax?

```
class PixKey
def cpf
    ^[0-9]{11}$
end
def cnpj
    ^[0-9]{14}$
end
def phone
    ^\+[1-9][0-9]\d{1,14}$
end
def email
    ^[a-z0-9.!#$&'*+\/=?^_`{
end
def evp
    [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
end
```

end

Comment: What should your class be doing? Just return the regular expression or should it directly modify a string?

Comment: You can also learn more about [regular expressions in Ruby](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/)

Comment: Christian, I have another .rb file with 69 tests written with Rspec. The goal that I have is to simply "Create an object that is capable to represent PixKey" - which is the class containing the keys that I posted in the first comment. Unfortunately, I don't have more information than this. I'm sorry.

I created the structure like you advised, but when I run the commands to start the tests, my terminal fills with the following message:

Failure/Error: subject(:pix_key) { described_class.new(key) }

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: Then, something else if required, e.g. converting a string that is passed a parameter. Maybe you can share some tests.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or data, in part because readers may want to cut-and-paste to test code they may suggest.

Comment: A class does not contain **keys**, and from your example code, you create what it is called **instance methods** in Ruby-speak. You can also calll them "functions", if you want. However of your method definitions are syntactically incorrect. A regular expression `^[0-9]{11}$` is literally written as i.e. `/^[0-9]{11}$/` or `%r(^[0-9]{11}$)` (the latter is more convenient if the regex itself contains slashes. Also, if your methods always return the same value, you may consider using constants instead of methods, i.e. `CPF = %r(^[0-9]{11}$)`. This depends on how you  use the class.

Comment: BTW, you could also consider using a constant object of type **Hash** for your purpose, i.e. `PixKey = {cpf: %r(^[0-9]{11}$), cnpj: %r(....), ...}`. In this case, you are using **symbols** (`:cpf`, `:cnpj`,...) as keys and regular expressions as values.

Comment: This is the code for evp verification, for example: 
  describe '#evp?' do
    context 'when receive a valid evp' do
      [
        '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000'
      ].each do |key|
        context "when key is #{key}" do
          let(:key) { key }

          it { is_expected.to be_an_evp }
        end
      end
    end

    context 'when receive an invalid evp' do
      [
        '75.928.551/0001-19',
      ].each do |key|
        context "when key is #{key}" do
          it { is_expected.not_to be_an_evp }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  end

Answer (score 3):

You can define regular expressions using the `/.../` [regular expression literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Regexp+Literals).

Since regular expressions are immutable, I would simply use constants:

```
class PixKey
  CPF = /^[0-9]{11}$/
  CNPJ = /^[0-9]{14}$/
  PHONE = /^\+[1-9][0-9]\d{1,14}$/
  EMAIL = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
  EVP = /[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/
end
```

In the above, I've changed the email regexp to the one suggested by the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address) because the one in your screenshot was probably destroyed by a markdown parser.

You can use the above like this:

```
PixKey::CPF.match?('12345678901')        #=> true
PixKey::CNPJ.match?('12345678901234')    #=> true
PixKey::PHONE.match?('+5510998765432')   #=> true
PixKey::EMAIL.match?('pix@bcb.gov.br')   #=> true
PixKey::EVP.match?('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000') #=> true
```

Of course, you're not limited to [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#match-3F-method), you can use any method from the [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html) class or pattern matching methods from [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html).

Note that in Ruby, `^` and `$` match beginning and end of *line* which can cause problems in multi-line strings:

```
string = "before
+5510998765432
after"

string.match?(PixKey::PHONE) #=> true
```

If you want to match beginning and end of *string* (i.e. only match whole strings), you can use `\A` and `\z` instead:

```
PixKey::PHONE = /\A\+[1-9][0-9]\d{1,14}\z/

string = "before
+5510998765432
after"

string.match?(PixKey::PHONE) #=> false

string = '+5510998765432'

string.match?(PixKey::PHONE) #=> true
```

Comment: Very cool, was not aware of that limitation with `^` and `$`

Answer (score 0):

To return the regular expressions for further use, you could return the regex using `/`:

```
class PixKey
  def cpf
      /^[0-9]{11}$/
  end
end
```

You could run `PixKey.new.cpf` to return the regex:

```
irb(main):022:0> PixKey.new.cpf
=> /^[0-9]{11}$/
```

You could also make it a class method by putting `self.` in front of the method name or add the line `class << self` as the first line in your class to make them all class methods by default (don't forget the end in this case).

```
class PixKey
  def self.cpf
      /^[0-9]{11}$/
  end
end
```

```
class PixKey
  class << self
    def cpf
      /^[0-9]{11}$/
    end
  end
end
```

With this you could run `PixKey.cpf` to return the regex:

```
irb(main):022:0> PixKey.cpf
=> /^[0-9]{11}$/
```